# Trouble installing Visual Foxpro 6 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-foxpro

I need to install Visual Foxpro 6 on my Windows 8 laptop.

I have the Visual Studio 6 CDs. I go through the installation and everything completes installing. However, after the progress bar completes and goes away, the green installation screen displays a message like "Configuring your setup" or "completing setup". But this screen never goes away. It just hangs until I "Close Program" it.

When I start VFP6, it opens but the Command window never displays. I do see the white VFP6 desktop, but it doesn't respond and I have to Close Program.

I tried copying the VFP6 files from the CD to the drive, but the same thing happens when I try to run VFP6, it doesn't respond and I have to Close Program.

I'm able to run VFP9 on this Win8 PC just fine. But I can't get VFP6 to install or run.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that VFP 6 is not even CLOSELY supported for Windows 8.  Another person I help periodically was running VFP 8 on a Windows 8 machine and it fails.  Apparently that was his consensus finding across the board for others he has communicated with.  I wouldn't even bother trying VFP 6 on Windows 8.

Comment: Actually,  I got it working. Running the VFP6.exe as Admin does it. Everything in VFP6 works just fine doing that.

Comment: @Jerry, Interesting...  but, now for production, are you going to have any other users "Running As Admin"?  bad choice...

Comment: Great question! This is an app I took over about 10 years ago. The business still runs on WinXP so no need for them to run as Admin. My DEV PC is Win8, so only I had a problem. I know I have to convert the app to VFP9 but this will require lots of testing mainly to ensure reports don't break. But I'm not sure business will see need for upgrade at the moment.

Comment: @Jerry, for reports that have data grouping and reprint headers, make sure you get the SP2 with HotFix 3.  Also, many issues with querying where group by does not include all non-aggregates will crash... Set EngineBehavior 80 helps that. But there are plenty of tips/traps converting to 9 you should be able to find on the net.